# Kotlin: Apply a suspend function on a list "in parallel"?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

If I have a `List<A>` and a function `suspend (A) -> B`, how can I apply this function on the list in parallel?

Comment: What do you mean by `in parallel`?

Answer (score 7):

```
coroutineScope {
    list.map {
        async {
            process(it)
        }
    } // List<Deferred<B>>
    .awaitAll() // List<B>
}

suspend fun process(a: A): B {
   ...
}
```

This assumes you are already in a `suspend` context. Otherwise, you need to launch a new coroutine on the appropriate scope instead of using the `coroutineScope` scoping function.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extension function on `CoroutineScope`, go through each element of the list and launch a coroutine for each element. In this way elements of the list will be processed in parallel. Some code snippet:

```
fun CoroutineScope.processListInParallel(list: List<A>): List<Deferred<B>> = list.map {
    async { // launch a coroutine
        processA(it)
    }
}

GlobalScope.launch {
    val list = listOf(A("name1"), A("name2"), A("name3"))
    val deferredList = processListInParallel(list)
    val results: List<B> = deferredList.awaitAll() // wait for all items to be processed
}

suspend fun processA(a: A): B {
    delay(1000) // emulate suspension
    return B("Result ${a.name}")
} 

data class A(val name: String) {}
data class B(val name: String) {}
```

**Note**: `GlobalScope` is used here as an example, using it is highly [discouraged](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/), application code usually should use an application-defined [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/index.html).